# Waiting until it is safe to shutdown self hosted SignalR

Tags: c#, signalr

I have a C# app that is self-hosting SignalR 2.0.3.

I am disposing the OWIN hosting components (the only way to shut down SignalR as far as I know) shortly before shutting down the process, as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var signalrHost = Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start(url);
  //do things
  signalrHost.Dispose();
  Console.WriteLine("Press [Enter] to exit ...");
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I know for a fact that no clients are invoking anything on the hub after the call to `Dispose`. Likewise the server is done invoking methods on the `HubContext` before calling `Dispose`.

And yet I assume there are internally queued messages that then error out when I call `Dispose`. That is to say, it appears that `Dispose` does not wait until everything for SignalR is "flushed".

I say that because my Console windows fills up with SignalR errors just before exiting, and connected clients don't get some of the final messages.

Now if I put in an arbitrary `Thread.Sleep` before the call to `Dispose`, everything shuts down cleanly. But that leaves me guessing how long to sleep.

Is there a way to know when I can call `Dispose` without causing these errors?

Comment: Why do you want to call dispose in the first place?  hubs are created and disposed automatically , when a client needs them or is finished with them. also see here https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2908

Comment: ill correct my question, but im not disposing of hubs directly, really just stopping the owin web app (you can see it in the code above)... i do it right before exiting the app, so it would happen automatically even if i don't call it directly, and the same problem exists where i need to sleep an undetermined amount of time to flush current activity that i prefer to not lose (it isn't infrastructure critical messaging per signalr recommendation, but still i'd like it to go out before closing the app)